# Powershell create a comma delimited list from array of IP's that occur $N number of times

Tags: arrays, windows, sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0

Everywhere I have looked has shown me methods of doing this that work with physical files but, for whatever reason, not with an array. I would rather not have this data stored, then called from a file and just work directly with the array if that is possible. I am stuck using PowerShell v2 but this should still be doable. I appreciate any and all help in advance.

I have an array called `$net_final` that has the following values:

```
63.232.3.102
63.232.3.102
64.339.161.5
64.339.161.5
64.339.161.5
64.339.161.5
64.339.161.5
64.339.161.5
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
19.19.19.19
63.339.161.7
63.339.161.7
63.339.161.7
63.339.161.7
63.339.161.7
```

I then do the following to get a list of IP's that occur 5 or more times in this array:

`($net_final | Group-Object | Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 5} | 
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -Property Name | Out-String).Trim()`

Which gets me this output:

```
64.339.161.5
19.19.19.19
63.339.161.7
```

However I cannot seem to get them comma delimited on the same line. Making a comma delimited list out of just the array is fairly uncomplicated with things like `$net_final -Join ","` and `($net_final | Select-Object -Unique) -Join ","`, but I need to grab array items that occur $N number of times.

**Expected output**:

`64.339.161.5,19.19.19.19,63.339.161.7`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here you go, a nice little one-liner for you:

```
($net_final|group|?{$_.count -ge 5}|Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
```

That will output:

```
64.339.161.5,19.19.19.19,63.339.161.7
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Works like a charm.  I cannot believe I was so close to the answer and didn't realize it. Frustrating, but again thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

I had trouble with the solution given by *TheMadTechnician*, but found the following works great:

`$my_array -join ","`

Comment: The problem with this is that it will give all IP's joined by commas, not just unique ones, and the original post only wanted it where there were 5 or more duplicates which this doesn't account for either. Your code returns all 15 IP addresses joined with commas.

Answer (score 5):

Even faster / simpler to read:

```
$test = (1,3,7,7,3,2,1)
$($test | sort -Unique) -join ","
```

1,2,3,7

You can pipe any array into sort with the -unique flag to dedupe; the wrapped variable can then be joined with your preferred delimiter.

Comment: This has the same issue as the answer by mgood1. This gathers all unique entries, where the requester only wanted items that repeat a certain number of times.